# Is there any tool to compare two files which are in japanese language

Tags: testing, localization

Is there any tool to compare two files which are in japanese language or other than english language.

Its related Globalization testing where the files are generated in pdf format in any of the foreign language other than english.

I need to compare the files and validate the text.

Comment: This sounds like a question for [Software Recommendations SE](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/). In any case, you will need to specify what types of files you are talking about, and what you mean by "compare". Surely, any diff tool can compare plain text files, no matter what language they are written in. If you want to compare across different encodings, that gets a tad more difficult, but it is still essentially a language-agnostic operation.

Comment: Since i cannot understand Chinese/japanese language, using a tool for instance Winmerge its coverts those language characters into unknown symbols.

Comment: What "unknown symbols" in particular? It seems that the default version of WinMerge (as opposed to something called *WinMergeU.exe*) does not support Unicode, so possibly WinMerge simply cannot load those files correctly.